# Hiding footer of the embedded webpage in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mydivclass').hide();
    });
    </script>
```

I am trying access Microsoft  Forms from my html using Iframe.
Is it possible to remove the footer of the microsoft forms .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents()` and `.find()` to find the specific element that you want to hide like `.mydivclass` with that class inside the `iframe`.

In your JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("iframe").contents().find(".mydivclass").hide();
});

</script>
```

Comment: I have hidden it but on pressing tab key or down arrow key, it is dispalyed again.